# Any way to avoid wrappers when implementing third party traits for third party structs

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a Rust library, which needs an asynchronous mpsc channel, however, I don't want to depend on any specific `async` runtime (e.g. `tokio`, `smol`), I'd like to let the users of the library choose which one to use, so I define traits:

```
struct Job { ... }

trait Sender {
    fn send(&mut self, job: Job);
}

trait Receiver {
    fn recv(&mut self) -> Future<Output = Option<Job>>;
}

fn foo(tx: impl Sender, rx: impl Receiver) {
    // ...
}
```

However, the library users have to create lots of wrappers on actually used runtime, e.g. for tokio:

```
// We have to create wrappers here, as both `mylib::Sender`
// and `tokio::Sender` are from third party libraries, we
// cannot implement `mylib::Sender` for `tokio::Sender` directly.

struct TokioSender(tokio::Sender);
struct TokioReceiver(tokio::Receiver);

impl mylib::Sender for TokioSender { ... }
impl mylib::Receiver for TokioReceiver { ... }


// Finally we can call the library function.
fn run() {
    ...
    let (tx, rx) = tokio::channel();
    mylib::foo(TokioSender(tx), TokioReceiver(rx));
    ...
}
```

The wrappers might be tedious if the traits have many functions. In Go, if a type `T` has all the functions defined by an interface `I`, then `T` implements `I` and can be passed around where the needed type is `I` without any extra efforts. So, is there any chance to do same thing here, make all `T`s that have the functions defined by the trait automatically implement the trait like Go, so that we don't need those wrappers anymore?

Or maybe any other workarounds?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the [futures](https://crates.io/crates/futures) crate is runtime agnostic.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Yes, the `futures` crate has nothing to do with runtimes, IMO, it **define**s behaviors, the runtimes **implement** the behaviors.

Comment: @KelvinHu That's not really accurate. The futures that the crate implements are basic enough that they don't need to know the inner workings of the runtime to function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't create a blanket implementation based on functions available on a type. There are only three ways a type implements a trait:

1. The owner of the trait implements it for the type.
2. The owner of the trait creates a blanket implementation which includes the type possibly bound on the *trait(s)* a type implements.
3. The owner of the struct implements the trait.

That's it.

So you can

1. create an implementation for all the types that should implement the trait in your library, probably [gated by a feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies) per runtime so the user can choose which runtimes they need supported.
2. submit patches to the runtimes that implement the trait (but usually their runtime wouldn't care for your library)
3. create a blanket implementation which covers all types you want (though this isn't going to work for `tokio` nor `smol` since `send` is an inherent function on their respective `Sender`s)
4. have the user create wrappers and implement the trait for exactly the types they want.

Of course you can write a derive macro:

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;

#[proc_macro_derive(Sender)]
fn derive_sender(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input: syn::DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    let t = input.ident;
    quote!{
        impl ::mycrate::Sender for #t {
            fn send(&mut self, job: ::mycrate::Job) {
                self.0.send(job);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or other macro to make 4 easier.

Comment: Thanks for the response, does option 1 require to make the library depending on all the runtimes?

Comment: Yes, at least optionally depending on the features.

Comment: OK... then I think option 4 is the only choice, and I might write a macro to simplify the wrapper definitions.